# Rospy Services with method class

Tags: ros, rospy, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How can i use a class method for rospy.Service()?

The .srv file is

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
bool response
```

The code in the server.py is

```
s = rospy.Service('setVelocity', SetVelocity, self.setVelocity)
```

The signature of the setVelocity method

```
def setVelocity (self, r, l)
```

In the client.py i've

```
s = rospy.ServiceProxy('setVelocity', SetVelocity)
s(3,5)
```

and i get this error:

```
error processing request: setVelocity() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Sorry for my bad english

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204231/rospy-services-with-method-class/) by [Dreadma](https://answers.ros.org/users/21776/dreadma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The service callback should only take one argument other than `self`, which will be of type `[YourService]Request`.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1